# Unbinding a listener/handler from an Element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a jsonSuggest jQuery plugin to show autocomplete data in an text box on the website.

To turn it ON I call:

```
$('input#editbox').jsonSuggest({url: someurl, onSelect:callbackFunc});
```

However I am unable to deactivate the auto-suggest once the it's been turned on. In particular, when I make another call for the same editbox with different parameters, 2 autocomplete boxes appear. So I would like to turn it OFF before turning it ON again with new parameters.

The code is only about 300 lines and available here

https://github.com/cootetom/jQuery-JSON-Suggest-Search-Box/blob/master/jquery.jsonSuggest-2.js

I ran through it with a debugger, but can not find the point where a listener is attached or a "bind" is made. Admittedly I am not 100% profficient in jQuery.

Thanks in advance

PS: Could this be part of the solution?

Calling

```
$('input#editbox').off("keyup");
$('input#editbox').off("keydown");
```

before calling

```
$('input#editbox').jsonSuggest(...)
```

again?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/cootetom/jQuery-JSON-Suggest-Search-Box/blob/master/jquery.jsonSuggest-2.js#L317

Thats where all the binding happens. So you need to unbind keyup, keydown, blur and focus events using `.off` like `$('input#editbox').off('keyup');`